# LoadInst and StoreInst Values and addresses LLVM

Tags: c++, c, llvm

I have a file print.c, which has two functions:

```
void printLoad(...) {
  // print address and value of memory location from which value
  printf("address=... value=...", ...); 
}

void printStore(...) {
  // print address and value of memory location from which value 
}
```

I have an LLVM pass which iterates over the instructions and adds CallInst instruction either printLoad or printStore (depending on the instruction type) after the current one (load/store inst).

In order to call this printStore or printLoad I need to add appropriate arguments to CallInst::Create function, which are the address and the value of the memory location.

This is an example of what I want to achieve:

```
define void @mains() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
  store i32 5, i32* %1, align 4
  store i32 2, i32* %2, align 4
  store i32 4, i32* %2, align 4
  %3 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
  %4 = add nsw i32 %3, 5
  store i32 %4, i32* %1, align 4
  ret void
}

The output should be:
  store instruction: 
    address=...   // address of %1
    value=0
  ...
  ...
  ...
  load instruction:
    address=...  // address of %2
    value=4
  store instruction:
    address=...  // address of %1
    value=9
```

**Progress so far:**

I am able to get the addresses of the operands using getPointerOperand() on LoadInst/StoreInst.

I can also get the value of StoreInst in the first 4 store instructions by casting the operand to ConstantInt, but I don't know how to extract the value in the last StoreInst. Is it even possible?

**EDITED:**

Using

```
void printLoad(int32_t p)
```

and

```
Constant *hookLoadFunc = M.getOrInsertFunction("printLoad", Type::getVoidTy(M.getContext()), Type::getInt32Ty(M.getContext()));
```

.

```
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca i32, align 4
  %3 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
  call void @printStore(i32 0)
  store i32 0, i32* %2, align 4
  call void @printStore(i32 0)
  store i32 5, i32* %2, align 4
  call void @printStore(i32 5)
  store i32 2, i32* %3, align 4
  call void @printStore(i32 2)
  store i32 4, i32* %3, align 4
  call void @printStore(i32 4)
  %4 = load i32, i32* %3, align 4
  %5 = add nsw i32 %4, 5
  store i32 %5, i32* %2, align 4
  call void @printStore(i32 %5)
  ret i32 0
  %2 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %0, i32* %2, align 4
  call void @printStore(i32 %0)
  %3 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
  %4 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([22 x i8], [22 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0), i32 %3)
  ret void
  %2 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %0, i32* %2, align 4
  call void @printStore(i32 %0)
  %3 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
  %4 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([22 x i8], [22 x i8]* @.str.1, i32 0, i32 0), i32 %3)
  ret void
```

This causes Segmentation fault: 11 when run.

**SOLVED:**

Figured out that I had infinity loop (due to recursion). **printStore** actually uses load/store instructions, thus creating another call to **printStore** and so on.

Comment: The operand should be an AddInst or something like that. Remember that the insns are equivalent with the value they represent. Perhaps http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BinaryOperator.html ?

Comment: To get the actual leaf int value, you could try a constant propagation transformation (including a preceding mem2reg pass to remove the pointers in favor of registers). But.. I am still not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want to actually run the code, or do you want a static analysis?

Comment: Is it possible to do a generic solution, not only for binary operator?

Comment: sounds like you want to actually run the code instead of analysing it? Which means you don't need to do anything special. Just pass the value operand to the call insns as an argument. And make the parameter of the function a int32_t.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you have an `llvm::Function` that represents `printLoad()` and `printStore()`:

```
llvm::Function * print_load = ....
llvm::Function * print_store = ...
```

You can emit a `CallInst` for each `LoadInst` and `StoreInst`.

For `LoadInst`:

```
LoadInst * some_load = ...
Value * address_of_load = some_load->getOperand(0);
Value * print_load_arguments[] = { address_of_load, some_load };

// Insert a CallInst just after the load.
CallInst::Create(print_load, print_load_arguments )->insertAfter( some_load );
```

Remember that in llvm the value loaded by the `LoadInst` is the same thing as the `LoadInst` itself.

For `StoreInst`:

```
StoreInst * some_store = ...
Value * value_to_store = some_store->getOperand(0);
Value * address_of_store = some_store->getOperand(1);
Value * print_store_arguments[] = { address_of_store, value_to_store };

// Insert a CallInst just after the store.
CallInst::Create(print_store, print_store_arguments)->insertAfter(some_store);
```

This will work if all the types match. Otherwise, you have to insert `BitCast` instructions just before calling `printStore()` or `printLoad()`.

Comment: I did that but got

"Instruction does not dominate all uses!
  %3 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
  call void @printLoad(i32 %3)
LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!"