# Locate cache index with LLVM instrumented code and compute cache stats

Tags: caching, clang, llvm

I instrumented LLVM bc code and for each Store/Load Inst, when dynamically executed, it will print out a physical address. Here is an example sequence:

```
Store : 0x7ffca642f8f4
Store : 0x6010a0
Load : 0x6010a0
```

Is there a way to figure out which cache index the instruction is accessing, if we don't know the CPU and system information? We can assume any setting we need, e.g. we can assume we are using 128 byte memory and 32 bytes 2-way set associate cache, etc. Note that in the sequence presented, some of them are 32-bit addresses and some of are 64-bit. I used  --relocation-model=pic for llc otherwise it gave me overflow error.

The ultimate goal is to compute cache hit/miss counts from the sequence.

The instrumented part is similar to this post: [LoadInst and StoreInst Values and addresses LLVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298766/loadinst-and-storeinst-values-and-addresses-llvm)

Comment: If you can assume anything you want about the cache architecture, perhaps you can assume that the cache offers suitable statistics?

Comment: @arnt By suitable statistics, do you mean something like this https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/devicemanagement/caching_stat_monitor.html? If so, I'm not sure how they are helpful. The goal is to compute the cache hit/miss counts if I were ambiguous.